# how do I make a function start at a certain hour

Tags: python, tkinter, alarm

I am making a program to enter a site automaticaly at a certain time(I know that are bether ways to do)
But this is a problem that the program does't wait till the right time, it just start automaticaly when press the buttom. I tried to do this like a alarm, a lot of alarm forms but it always is the same. How I do this work? thanks. Here is a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
import pynput
from datetime import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
win = Tk()
win.title('autoclass.enter V1')
win.geometry('500x300')

hora= Entry(win, width=30)
hora.place(x=178, y=100)
hour = hora.get()

def start():

    while(1 == 1):
        won = str(datetime.now().time())
        now = (won[11:10])
        print(now)
        if (hour == now):
            print(now)
        
            stop = True
        
            pyautogui.click(a, b)
            time.sleep(g)
            pyautogui.moveTo(c, d, duration = 1)#I had change the numbers by letters to not destroi ur dektop
            pyautogui.click(e, f)
            keyboard = Controller()
            time.sleep(2)
            time.sleep(8)
            keyboard.type(hello)
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)
            keyboard.release(Key.enter)
            break

myLabel6 = Label(win, text='the hour(like this 7:30')
myLabel6.place(x=195, y=78)

button = Button(win, text='start', command=start)
button.place(x=50, y=80)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any research into tkinter's `after` method, for scheduling code to run in the future?

Comment: First you get the `hour` right after the `hora` is created, so `hour` is empty string.  Second you assign `won[11:10]` (which is empty because start index is larger than the end index) to `now`, and so `now` is also empty.  Therefore `if hour == now:` will be True.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` module and the `while` loop to check whether the current time  is equal to the time that you want.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
desired_time = '13:28'
while True:
    if strftime("%H:%M", gmtime()) == desired_time:
        main()
```

But in Tkinter the `while loop` will freeze the program. I suggest to make a function which checks the time according to that `if` statement

```
def time_checker():
    if strftime("%H:%M", gmtime()) == desired_time:
        main()
```

Comment: You don't explain how to call `time_checker`. If you call it just once it won't be very useful.

Comment: aparently no, it still intantly start when press the start button

Comment: @PedroFontoura did you assigned to the button the `time_checker` function and placed an if statement and below that the function that should fire>?

Comment: yes I did change the Button command to `time_checker`, but now it doesn't do nothing

Comment: @PedroFontoura can you link me the code, please? I will try to fix that for you ;)